# How should I configure paths to other exe files in my project?

Tags: c#, filepath, settings.settings

I am working on a project that requires a **.exe** file to be executed by the application. The problem here is that I cannot guarantee that the file will always be in the same location on the user's machine, my app has no way of knowing where this **.exe** file is located.

So for example, my application needs to execute **mongod.exe** which is located (by default) in the following location: **C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin\mongod.exe**.

The problem here is that this is not always the case, the user might have installed this application to a different place, so I can't assume that the path to the **.exe** file is always the same on every client.

Currently I am using the **Settings.settings** file to store a default file path to the file:

[image: A setting in the Settings.settings file]

The user can then either edit the **app.config** file or I could provide a UI to allow the user to change the file path.

So my question is, is there a better way?

Comment: Why not have the application crawl the disk and look for the .exe.  Then ask the user to confirm that the chosen file is really what is intended.  This is especially useful if there is more than one of such files.  One problem you may have though is versions change on the same machine. You will need to program a recovery/rediscovery process.

Comment: Look into `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\`

Answer (score 0):

Searching the path of the Mongodb.exe file in Registry can be useful. Try to find the exe path from the Registry entry.

RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\MongoDB\MongoDB Connector");
            if (key != null)
            {
                Object o = key.GetValue("InstallPath");
            }

Object o will give the path of MongoDB.exe file.

P.S.: If your application does not have rights to access the local machine's registry, then this approach won't work